# Can't seem to debug this CakePhp code.

Tags: javascript, php, debugging, cakephp

This should be simple, you click on a link ( a button) and it asks you a question - yes or no, you answer and it should do it.  The button you click on before you click on it has the data id of the field:

Not Received

A pop up comes up and you either respond yes or no.  If you respond yes, it should put the order you choose into a Past Orders page/list and if you say No the order should remain in your dashboard list.

What is happening is the pop up comes up and no matter if you push yes or no, an item gets put into Past Orders and it is not the item you wanted to be put there.  It is the first one in the list on the page of orders on your dashboard.  I have posted the section on this button from the View page, the controller page and the javascript page.  Does anyone see anything that doesn't add up?

```
//$(function() {
function initConformOn(){
        $('.btn_confirm').confirmOn({            
            questionText: 'Have You Received the Goods?',
            textYes: 'Yes',
            textNo: 'No'
        }
        ,'click', function(e, confirmed)
        {
            //console.log();
            var id= $(this).data("id");
            var received = $(this).data("received");
            if(confirmed) $(this).remove();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?php echo $this->webroot?>staff_orders/change_received',
                    data: {id:id,received:received},
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'HTML',
                    success: function (data){
                        //alert(data);
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });           
        });
}
 //});

</script>
```

I found more code in another script that ties into this - it could be a problem in that one too or one or the other.

```
dataIndex: 'isreceived',

            header: 'Received Status ',

            filter: {

                type: 'list',



                options: ['0', '1']

            },





            renderer: function(val, meta, record){

               // alert(record.data.status);

                if(record.data.isreceived == '1'){
                    return '<span style="color:#329933;font-weight:bold">Received</span>';
                }
                else if(record.data.super_admin_status != '1')
                {
                    return '<span style="font-weight:bold">Not Received</span>';
                }
                else{



                    return '<span style="color:#ED2326;font-weight:bold"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn_confirm" data-id="'+record.data.id+'" data-received="'+record.data.isreceived+'">Not Received</a></span>';



                }



            }

        },
```

And the controller code

```
 function change_received()
    {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
        $recieve = $_REQUEST['received'];

        $recieve = $recieve == 0 ? 1 : 0;

        if(($id!="")&&($recieve!=""))
        {
            //$this->Order->update(array('Order.isreceived'=>$recieve),array('Order.id'=>$id));
            $this->data['Order']['isreceived'] = $recieve;
            $this->Order->id = $id;

            if($this->Order->save($this->data)){
                 $sql = "Update crontabs set crontabs.email_status = '1' where crontabs.order_id='{$id}' and crontabs.email_status='0'";
                $this->Crontab->query($sql);
                echo 'true';
            }
            else{
                echo 'false';
            }

            exit;
            //$this->redirect('/staff_orders/list_all');
        }
    }
```

Comment: you might need to check if confirmed is actually false to prevent it being removed if no selected
`if(confirmed===false) $(this).remove();`

Comment: Debug in what way? What isn't working? Are there errors?

Comment: That's the problem, there are no errors that after all my googling don't matter, It just doesn't work right, it puts the active orders in past orders whether you say yes or no and it doesn't put the order in past orders that you actually want in it.  I am hoping someone sees something I don't.  when you click on the pop up box that says Yes or No - That's where it goes wrong - it seems like it worked but it doesn't.

Comment: you can debug javascript using the developer tools of your web browser.

Comment: I've tried, Firefox, Firebug, Firefox Developer, Chrome Web developer, used PHPstorm and Netbeans watched videos on debugging, searched this site, it can't be this hard?

Comment: are you checking the text Yes or number 1 or Boolean ? how the check happen?

Comment: When you say checking the text, I know that 0 is No and 1 is Yes.  It reflects the data in the database field for isReceived.  I can't seem to figure out what happens when I click on Yes or No - I have narrowed it down to the to pieces of code - the first piece is in the index.ctp for staff dashboard and the second piece is in a separate javascript file.

Comment: I think `$recieve = $recieve == 0 ? 1 : 0;` should be something like `$recieve = $recieve == 1 ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: Thanks for your help.  That didn't work but I guess your thinking it is the controller code that is the problem and not in the javascript?

Comment: First thing that might be causing an issue is using `$_REQUEST` superglobal. It would be better to use the `$this->request->data` property here. Have you checked what the actual values of your `$id` and `$receive` are when it is saved? Are the correct values being saved to the database and just the display that is wrong, or are the incorrect values being saved?

Comment: The id is fine, the is received passes to the database for the item that is first in the grid even if you tell it no it hasn't been received it goes to the database as received and the item you chose stays as unreceived.  I comment out the superglobal and everything still works the same - no errors just doesn't do what it is supposed to.